# c3 chart.load with multiple charts

Tags: javascript, css, graph, charts, c3.js

I am using c3.js and c3.css to make several graphs on one page. I have multiple charts and want to update the data every 60 seconds so I use set interval, get the updated data, and then load it to a chart, however, it puts all of the data in the most recently made chart. I attempted to add a bindto to the data so it goes to the correct graph, but it still loads onto the bottom graph. how can I fix this?

```
...
<div id='chart1'></div>
<div id='chart2'></div>
...
function update()//this function collects the new data in arrays cols and xrows
...
setInterval(function(){
  update();
  chart.unload();
  chart.load({bindto:'#chart1',columns:cols, xs:xrows});
},3000);
```

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: how did you manage to do this?

Comment: It looks like he is overwriting the `chart` variable, so that is why it always updates the last chart only

Answer (score 2):

For showing update data atfirst

- hide previous data's DIV
- Use CLEAR to for cleaning Data
- Again Load the DIV

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's still looking to do this I've found a solution.

When you generate each chart, the declaration ends with:

```
}); }, chart = generate();
```

If you rename chart like so:

```
}); }, first_chart = generate();
```

Then you can manipulate that chart like so:

```
first_chart.load ({ <some_stuff> })
```

Give each chart variable a distinct name and you can edit them distinctly.